# Implementation of Push Server independent of Mobile Device Platform

Tags: push, push-notification, server-push, mobile-devices

I was wondering whether it is a feasible option to write a push server of my own for a mobile device. By this, I want to mean that I do not want to use neither APNS for Apple, nor C2DM for Android, nor BIS for Blackberry. I would like to implement a push server which can send notification to the mobile devices independent of platforms. Can you please provide any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

[notifo](http://notifo.com/) has an [api](https://api.notifo.com/) to sent notifications to phones. Right now it does [not yet support BB](http://notifo.com/mobile_apps/blackberry), but it does already support, Android(Beta), Iphone. I sent a message in the past how long it took to support Android 1.5 on my LG GW620 and they replied instantly saying that I should try [openetna](http://openetna.com/openetna/) because they would not support that version. I am still very glad for that answer because the latest android 2.2 is awesome compared to 1.5(I can install a lot more programs from market place and I can now use C2DM(AWESOME))..

Comment: I actually want to implement and deploy the server itself. For example, the mosquito server which can be deployed for providing push service for Android platform.